# Have Amazon Appstore webapp exit on suspend?

Tags: kindle-fire, kindle, amazon-appstore

We have an app as part of the Amazon Appstore webapp program, which allows web-apps to natively appear in their Appstore on e.g. Kindle Fire HDX. Our problem: The app doesn't exit and clear when closed, it's eternally stored in some persistent cache, causing issues with our concept of user sessions, websockets, remote user syncing and so on (it's a massively-multiplayer virtual world). How can we force the app to properly clear itself when being closed by the user?

(In XCode settings, a comparable boolean would be "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend"...)

Comment: Does the Page Visibily API help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: Did it help? kinda curious to see if it solved the problem

Comment: Yes, we did a test using this code and it did solve it: we were able to launch an alert showing the time of closing (an alert that is seen when reopening). Thanks!

Comment: dang, I should have gone for the bounty answer! but serious... glad it helped

Comment: Sigh, now I'm trying the same sample page again, and it doesn't work anymore. I'm closing Silk on my Kindle but the event is never caught. Strange.

Comment: Now got something working! if (isKindle) { window.onblur = window.onpagehide = function(e) { /* doStuff(); */ }; } // subject to Webapp test, but works in Silk

Comment: @Offbeatmammal - Re bounty: Please add your comment as an answer, it looks like the only one we will get ;)

Answer (score 2):

my initial suggestion was to use the PageVisibility API http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/ (as suggested here [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)) but it looks like it also requires some more robust checking taking advantage of window.onblur as well per your own comment above

```
if (isKindle) { window.onblur = window.onpagehide = function(e) { /* doStuff(); */ }; }
```

Comment: Sigh. While this worked in the Silk browser, it's not firing now in the Webapp context where we needed it...

Comment: ugh. I'll have a play, but traveling over the w/e